# Upstream branch not stored as remote-tracking branch

Tags: git, bash, branch

I'm writing a git script to check updatedness for all branches.

```
if [[ -n $(git config --get branch.$SHORT.remote) ]]; then
    LOCAL=$(git rev-parse "$SHORT")
    REMOTE=$(git rev-parse "$SHORT"@{upstream})
    BASE=$(git merge-base "$SHORT" "$SHORT"@{upstream})

    if [ $LOCAL = $REMOTE ]; then
        echo "Up-to-date"
    elif [ $LOCAL = $BASE ]; then
        echo "Need to pull"
    elif [ $REMOTE = $BASE ]; then
        echo "Need to push"
    else
        echo "Diverged"
    fi
else
    echo "No upstream configured."
fi
```

It gives me this error (twice, once for each @{upstream}):

```
fatal: Upstream branch 'refs/heads/master' not stored as a remote-tracking branch
fatal: Upstream branch 'refs/heads/master' not stored as a remote-tracking branch
```

Here is my `git branch -a`:

```
  master
* scrimmage
  remotes/origin/development
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/scrimmage
  remotes/origin/scrimmage-simple
```

What?? I don't understand any of this terminology, and can't find any reference to it except in some obscure mailing list where they decided to use this error message.

Comment: Are you sure that's from the `rev-parse` commands? I would think the two `@{upstream}` refs would be the problem here and the issue would be that there isn't a local tracking branch for that upstream branch. Do you have a local `.git/refs/remotes/<remote>/<ref>` entry for that branch?

Comment: I thought that @{upstream} was part of the rev-parse thing. Hm. Editing.

Comment: You can trivially recreate a similar (if not identical) situation with `git init foo; cd foo; git commit --allow-empty -m foo` then adding the config listed in [this email](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/195476) to your `.git/config` and run `git show master@{u}`.

Comment: Usually when there's no upstream it says so: `no upstream branch configured for this branch` or something. Why doesn't it say that here?

Comment: Because you have one configured only there isn't a tracking ref for it. That's the point of this message. To distinguish that case. What's the config say about the branch in question?

Answer (score 1):

I was being stupid; I had written a script earlier that apparently added a line

```
branch.master.remote=returns
```

to the config. Thus, it tried to access a remote which doesn't actually exist anywhere.

[Can this question be deleted, since it's such a specific case?]